# How do you move files to zip folder and then download them with code in Google colab?

Tags: zip, google-colaboratory

Here's a simplified version of a list of files I would normally have in Google colab's default `'/content/'` directory:

```
Prod_Online_CSV_Table.csv
Prod_Online_CSV_Table.csv
Project - Prod chart.png
Project Report.html
Project Report.xlsx
```

Using code, I want to move the two csv tables to a zip folder and the other three files to a different zip folder. I then want to download both zip folders to my C drive as part of the code rather than manually with the colab UI.

Note, there are other csv tables that I don't want to move to the zip folder.

All I've found online is about creating new directories and moving them there, but not about moving them to a zip folder to download them.

Any ideas?